# RegEx for subdomain with varying number

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Javascript RegExp, I'm trying to match URL like the following:

```
http://sub.domain.com/
http://sub1.domain.com/
http://sub100.domain.com/
```

I tried the following regex, which isn't working - not sure what I'm doing wrong ?

```
^http\:\/\/sub\d*\.domain\.com\/$
```

**EDIT:** fixed copy & paste typo

**Update:** For some reason, `document.location.href` doesn't match the regex - even though examples below (also on regex101.com) do work as expected. My workaround for now - I just match any subdomain.

..any help is much appreciated!

Comment: "app.clicktale.com" obviously won't match "domain.com". Along these lines I don't know if `subs` is a typo for `sub` or if your examples are completely irrelevant.

Comment: The examples you give and the regexp have little in common: sub instead subs, for example

Comment: Apologies - copy & paste typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the sub-domains you showed have the token "sub", but your REGEX is looking for "subs".

Also, no need to escape colons.

You don't say whether you wish to test for a match or actually capture the sub-domain. I'll assume the latter:

```
var match = "http://foo.bar.com".match(/https?:\/\/(([^.]+)\.)?/);
alert(match[2]); //"foo"
```

Comment: The examples also show "domain.com" while the regex is looking for "app.clicktale.com". The examples can't really be used to check for typos.

Comment: @Utkanos - thanks. I ended up applying a workaround, but that was the closest to what I needed - much obliged

Answer (score 1):

i dont understand How you can compare a grape with a mango

here is the corrected regex :

```
 /^http\:\/\/subs\d*\.app\.clicktale\.com\/$/.test("http://subs14.app.clicktale.com/");
```

run this command in your console, right now.

you will get true , if you use `search` then you will get `0` because the index of your match is `0`

Comment: You can make the last `\/` optional using `?` in case the input is `http://sub.domain.com` only.

Comment: @aelor For some reason, this doesn't seem to work for me when comparing with `document.location.href.search(regexHere)` I always get -1, unless I hardcode the digits that come after `sub`

Comment: @UJC what is the value of `document.location.href` that you are getting ?

Comment: @aelor the value is: `http://subs14.app.clicktale.com/`

* When testing this string through regex101.com it works perfectly as expected. When testing through the console I get -1...ideas ?

Comment: dude in the regex mentioned you need to replace the domain with your own domain, nyways I will update the answer, this will surely work